# C++ standard version supports/requirements of building compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, build, clang

1. What is the maximum version number of the `clang` compiler that can be built on a C++98-only compiler?
2. What is the minimum version number of the `clang` compiler that requires to build its source code on a C++11-compatible compiler?
3. What is the maximum version number of the `gcc` compiler that can be built on a C++98-only compiler?
4. What is the minimum version number of the `gcc` compiler that requires to build its source code on a C++11-compatible compiler?

Comment: You could answer your own questions with a good `git bisect`.

Comment: Are you interested in bootstrapping native compiler or building a cross compiler?

Comment: @ÖöTiib bootstrapping a native compiler

Comment: I can answer 3 and 4. gcc bootstraps itself, it doesn't need c++ compiler at all, and it uses very limited C features for step 1 build. I do not think you can find the C compiler which would not be able to bootstrap gcc.

Comment: @SergeyA  I need to bootstrap g++ too, rather than "pure" gcc without g++.

Comment: @Victor, when I said gcc, I meant the whole suite. It bootstraps everything (everything you configured, of course)

Comment: @SergeyA GCC needs a C++98 compiler to bootstrap. Only really old versions are fine with a C compiler as the bootstrap compiler.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer it was a while since I did it last time. Thanks for correcting me! For future readers, here is the link to specs: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html